# Joining to only one row in child table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL, and I have an `orders` table and an `order_items` table. An `order` can have many `order_items`. The foreign key in `order_items` is `orderId`. In my database there are 26 `orders` and 69 `order_items`. I want to get all `orders`, while joining to the `order_items` table - but only joining to one  `order_item` for each `order`. So the result should be 26 rows.

```
select o.*, oi.amount from orders o
JOIN order_items oi on o.id = (select orderId from order_items where orderId = 
o.id group by orderId);
```

orders Table:

```
id
email
total
createdTimestamp
```

order_items table:

```
id
orderId
amount 
status
```

Somehow, this is giving me 1794 rows back when I expect 26, and I am drawing a complete blank at to what is going on.

**It does not mater which order_item row is joined to for each order.**

**EDIT**

This will work:

```
  select o.*, oi.amount from order_items oi
  join orders o on o.id = oi.orderId
  group by oi.orderId;
```

But how can it be done by using the `orders` table in the `from` and joining to `order_items`?

Comment: The query you show only returns columns for `orders`, and you say you want all orders. So why not just _don't_ do the join? Just `select * from orders;`?

Comment: @BillKarwin I needed columns from order_items too, edited

Answer (score 1):

If you want one item per order, then use window functions:

```
select o.*, ol.*
from orders o join
     (select ol.*,
             row_number() over (partition by orderId order by rand()) as seqnum
     from order_items oi
    ) oi
    on o.id = oi.orderId and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Can you explain this? It seems overly complex for what I need. It does not matter which row in order_items is used per order

Comment: @Mark . . . This is simpler than your query, so I'm not sure where "overly complex" comes from.

Comment: `row_number() over (partition by orderId order by rand()) as seqnum` This is pretty unusual for Mysql, any explanation?

Comment: @Mark . . . This is standard SQL and has been part of the language for decades.  Happily, MySQL started supporting **this standard functionality** a few years ago.  A good place to start learning about window functions is the document:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html.